# dropdown rows in primeng table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, primeng

I would like to create table with many rows but only one should be visible, rest should be hidden.

[image]

After clicking on one of arrows rows should appears below or above main row depending if this is "up" arrow or "down arrow"

[image]

I'm using angular and primeng. Do you have some ideas how to achieve something like that?